# Timeout for asynchronous Task<T> with additional exception handling

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timeout, interop

In my project, I reference types and interfaces from a dynamic link library.
The very first thing I have to do when using this specific library is to create an instance of `EA.Repository`, which is defined within the library and serves as kind of an entry point for further usage.

The instantiation `EA.Repository repository = new EA.Repository()` performs some complex stuff in the background, and I find myself confronted with three possible outcomes:

1. Instantiation takes some time but finishes successfully in the end
2. An exception is thrown (either immediately or after some time)
3. The instantiation blocks forever (in which case I'd like to cancel and inform the user)

I was able to come up with an asynchronous approach using `Task`:

```cs
public static void Connect()
{
    // Do the lengthy instantiation asynchronously
    Task<EA.Repository> task = Task.Run(() => { return new EA.Repository(); });

    bool isCompletedInTime;

    try
    {
        // Timeout after 5.0 seconds
        isCompletedInTime = task.Wait(5000);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // If the instantiation fails (in time), throw a custom exception
        throw new ConnectionException();
    }

    if (isCompletedInTime)
    {
        // If the instantiation finishes in time, store the object for later
        EapManager.Repository = task.Result;
    }
    else
    {       
        // If the instantiation did not finish in time, throw a custom exception
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
}
```

(I know, you can probably already spot a lot of issues here. Please be patient with me... Recommendations would be appreciated!)

This approach works so far - I can simulate both the "exception" and the "timeout" scenario and I obtain the desired behavior.

However, I have identified another edge case: Let's assume the instantiation task takes long enough that the timeout expires and then throws an exception. In this case, I sometimes end up with an `AggregateException` saying that the task has not been observed.

I'm struggling to find a feasible solution to this. I can't really cancel the task when the timeout expires, because the blocking instantiation obviously prevents me from using the `CancellationToken` approach.

The only thing I could come up with is to start observing the task asynchronously (i.e. start another task) right before throwing my custom `TimeoutException`:

```cs
Task observerTask = Task.Run(() => {
    try { task.Wait(); }
    catch (Exception) { }
});

throw new TimeoutException();
```

Of course, if the instantiation really blocks forever, I already had the first task never finish. With the observer task, now I even have two!

I'm quite insecure about this whole approach, so any advice would be welcome!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Framework 4 or below? .NET Framework 4.5 and above ignores unobserved task exceptions, unless you tell it explicitly to do otherwise by using the `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"` setting in `App.config` [(documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/throwunobservedtaskexceptions-element).

Comment: Good point! I did not know that this behavior is configurable. My application is targeting .NET framework 4.6.1. However, I get the mentioned exception even though my `App.config` does not specify the `<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions>` tag, i.e. it should default to `false`. Anyway, maybe it's even better to have unobserved tasks throw exceptions since it points out that I did not handle the task properly, right?

Comment: Strange. Try handling the static [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception) event, and invoke the `SetObserved()` method of the event's `args`. No, it's not OK to have to deal with these exceptions, because they are raised non-deterministically, when the garbage collector recycles an unreferenced `Task`.

Comment: Oh, that's right... I actually already handle the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event and invoke `SetObserved()`. But afterwards I write the exception to a log file, inform the user and try to gracefully shutdown the application. Is my thinking wrong in this point, then? Should I consider unobserved task exceptions as "not of interest anymore because I abandoned the task on purpose" and just discard the exception silently?

Comment: Take a look at this video: [The zen of async: Best practices for best performance](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T). At minute 59:07 Stephen Toub is asked about unobserved exceptions and TPL, and for the next 3-4 minutes he explains how and why these decisions were made.

Comment: Good to know both sides of the argument (thank you very much for the effort of pointing me to the exact timestamp in the video, by the way!)
I think, at least for the time being, I will stick with my "unobserved task exceptions are fishy, try not to abandon tasks" approach because it points out that something in my task goes wrong which I did not account for. Nevertheless, I now understand the non-deterministic behavior of these kind of exceptions and that the point in time at which they are thrown doesn't really say much...

Comment: Yeap, I guess it depends on what type of tasks you have, and how important it is to prevent your application from running with a potentially corrupted state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an extension method that you could use to explicitly observe the tasks that may fail while unobserved:

```
public static Task<T> AsObserved<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    task.ContinueWith(t => t.Exception);
    return task;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => new EA.Repository()).AsObserved();
```

Comment: That's a good idea! Using `ContinueWith()`, I can now explicitly acknowledge that I leave the task on its own but that I'm aware it might complete or fail later on (the `TaskContinuationOptions` even give me some flexibility). If I ever abandon a task carelessly and it fails, the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event handler will still catch it. Can't believe that I came up with immediately starting an observer task, but not with starting a "catch task" only when really needed... Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure Mr Nobody! And yep, setting the flag `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` should make even more obvious the intentions if this small piece of software. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I fully understood what you're trying to achieve, but what if you do something like this -

```
public static void Connect()
{
    Task<EA.Repository> _realWork = Task.Run(() => { return new EA.Repository(); });
    Task _timeoutTask = Task.Delay(5000);
    Task.WaitAny(new Task[]{_realWork, timeoutTask});
    if (_timeoutTask.Completed)
    {
        // timed out
    }
    else
    {
        // all good, access _realWork.Result
    }
}
```

or you can even go a bit shorter -

```
public static void Connect()
{
    Task<EA.Repository> _realWork = Task.Run(() => { return new EA.Repository(); });
    var completedTaskIndex = Task.WaitAny(new Task[]{_realWork}, 5000);
    if (completedTaskIndex == -1)
    {
        // timed out
    }
    else
    {
        // all good, access _realWork.Result
    }
}
```

You can also always [call `Task.Run` with a `CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitany?view=netframework-4.8) that will time out, but that will raise an exception - the above solutions give you control of the behaviour without an exception being thrown (even though you can always `try/catch`)

Comment: This version actually seems rather neat! May I point out that in your first suggestion you probably meant something like `Task _timeoutTask = Task.Run(() => { Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); });` because otherwise the `_timeoutTask` always seems to have its `IsCompleted` property set because it never executed.
I have tried to adapt your solution so that the expected exceptions in the `_realWork` task get caught, but I end up with the same edge case I mentioned. I guess my problem essentially boils down to the old "how to cancel a non-cancellable task" question :-/